# I need to regenerate the ufw files

Tags: ubuntu, ip, firewall, ufw

I deleted the ufw files in `/etc/ufw/`, so I can start from scratch with a new generated port file. But after I deleted ufw per apt-get and reinstalled it, the files do not get generated. So what am I now supposed to do?

I get many connections from "outside", like `122.246.16.251:80` to every single port of my local ubuntu-server. With ufw I want to prevent this. The question is how.

So my primary question is: How do I get new generated ufw-files after delting them?

And my secondary question is: How can I block, maybe every IP from middle-east and only let europe IPs connect to my server.

Comment: When you tried to reinstall ufw, did you get any error messages like `Not replacing deleted config file /etc/ufw/before.rules`

Comment: I can't remember... A friend tried it with reinstalling and boom, the files get generated...strange thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove and install ufw, but you need to use `apt-get remove --purge`

`sudo apt-get remove --purge ufw`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall ufw
```